# Multivariate Time Series Forecasting using Pytorch TimeSeriesDataSet

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, forecasting, multivariate-time-series

[image]

I want to forecast a **Target** using its history and the history of covariates (**Cov1, Cov2,Cov3**).

I have several samples (**Id**) each of them with 601 observations (**time**) of (**Target, Cov1, Cov2,Cov3**) and want to train my model (a TemporalFusionTransformer model) on the 1st 60 observations to predict the 541 remaining **Target** values.

I plan to train/validate my model using Pytorch TimeSeriesDataSet object and then test it on unseen samples.

I readed a lot of Pytorch TimeSeriesDataSet examples (pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io , Kaggle notebooks, data scientist posts like https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-n-hits-the-latest-breakthrough-in-time-series-forecasting-a8ddcb27b0d5...) but most of them subset a single timeseries example in consecutive train/validation/test sets.

I don't find that many examples training on several samples  and testing on others.
So my questions are about data preprocessing prior to fit my model.
Here is the code I used:

```
max_prediction_length = 540
max_encoder_length = 61 
training_cutoff = df["time"].max() - max_prediction_length

training = TimeSeriesDataSet(df[lambda x: x.time <= training_cutoff],
time_idx="time",target="Target", group_ids=["id"], 
min_encoder_length= max_encoder_length,max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
min_prediction_length=max_prediction_length, max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length, 
time_varying_unknown_reals=["Cov1", "Cov2",”Cov3”,”Target”])

# creating validation set (predict=True) which means to predict the last max_prediction_length points in time for each series:
validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training,df_patients, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)

# create dataloaders for model:
batch_size = 4
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
```

1. I’m not sure if I should use `df[lambda x: x.time <= training_cutoff]` like I see on code examples I found (instead of `df`) if I use `min_encoder_length= max_encoder_length, max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,  min_prediction_length=max_prediction_length, max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length` as length parameters ?
2. I still don't clearly understand how the boolean `predict=True`, `stop_randomization=True` & `train=True/False` work to differentiate training and validation sets

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? my problem is like yours except that I only have 14 observation by sample(ID).